# SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper in Lucene.NET?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

Does anyone know if the SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper class is available in the Lucene.NET port? I can't find it anywhere, and it sure would be handy. I'm still using version 2.9...maybe it's available in a later version? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see it in the current codebase:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/trunk/src/core/Search/Spans/

You could probably port it easily enough though.

Comment: The relevant Java source code is here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_1/lucene/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper.java ... and it looks fairly straightforward to port.

Answer (score 0):

[SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/master/src/Lucene.Net/Search/Spans/SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper.cs) is available on [Lucene.Net 4.8.0-beta00004](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net/4.8.0-beta00004).

If you need support in earlier versions of Lucene.Net, you can probably just grab the source code from the above link and any dependencies and drop them into a library for your applications.