# Lucene .net + equivalent of SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper<MultiTermQuery> in C#

Tags: lucene.net

I need to convert the following Java code to C# but I couldn't find the equivalent of "SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper". Could you please help?

```
FuzzyQuery firstNameQuery = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("text", firstName), 2);
FuzzyQuery lastNameQuery = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("text", lastName), 2);

SpanQuery[] clauses = new SpanQuery[] {
  new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper<MultiTermQuery>(firstNameQuery),
  new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper<MultiTermQuery>(lastNameQuery)
};
SpanNearQuery spanNearQuery = new SpanNearQuery(clauses, 3, false);
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933000/spanmultitermquerywrapper-in-lucene-net). While there is no accepted answer, there are hints to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/master/src/Lucene.Net/Search/Spans/SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper.cs) and [MultiTermQuery](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/master/src/Lucene.Net/Search/MultiTermQuery.cs) are both available on [Lucene.Net 4.8.0-beta00004](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net/4.8.0-beta00004).

If you need support in earlier versions of Lucene.Net, you can probably just grab the source code from the above links and any dependencies and drop them into a library for your applications.